# Razor - Inline helper with multiple tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, helper

I can call a method which accepts an HTML/Razor block as a parameter like so:

`@Html.SiteText(@<div>Some content</div>)`

Calling the same method with multiple top level tags fails due to a parser error. I.E.

`@Html.SiteText(@<div>Some content</div><div>Some more content</div>)`

fails with:
`Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected`

Is there any way to pass a Razor helper which has multiple top level tags?

Edit:

Here's the signature of the SiteText extension method:

`public static IHtmlString SiteText(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Func<object, HelperResult> content)`

The actual implementation of the method shouldn't matter, as this applies to how the method is invoked rather than what the implementation does with the inputs.

Comment: Can you post the code to `@Html.SiteText()` please? Cheers.

Comment: @JasonEvans I can't post all of the implementation as it's proprietary, but I've added the method signature to the question. The implementation shouldn't matter, as my question is about how the method is invoked from Razor rather than what the implementation does with the inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to look at it is that the Razor view engine is looking at each of those div tags as a single property.

Wrapping them in a **text** tag should resolve the issue:

```
@Html.SiteText(@<text><div>Some content</div><div>Some more content</div></text>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but I suspect this will solve it:

```
@Html.SiteText(@<text>
    <div>Some content</div>
    <div>Some more content</div>
</text>)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but I accepted the other one because it was first, sorry!